# React Changing Background Image Dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I wrote this codes for changing background image according to user's selected. But The background image neither loads nor changes Please help me, I can not develope my own project.

```
const [selectedBgImg,setSelectedBgImg] = useState('../images/forestBg.jpg');
return(
<div className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center z-50  bg-cover`} style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${selectedBgImg})`}}>
    <select value={selectedBgImg} className='cursor-pointer' name="selectedBg"  onChange={(e)=>{setSelectedBgImg(e.target.value)}}>
                <option value="../images/forestBg.jpg">Forest</option>
                <option value="../images/seaBg.jpg">Sea</option>
                <option value="../images/libraryBg.jpg">Library</option>
              </select>
</div>)
```

Answer (score 1):

See different coding practices are considered while developing any library or framework according to their applications & versions.
In React, all the code written ultimately gets compiled into static files which are then served for hosting the web page. There is `index.html` file in `public` folder which is finally built for deploying purposes.
Hence, the component you've written is finally compressed and compiled in `index.html` file in public folder, and your relative paths become associated with that directory i.e. `public` folder. Hence, your problem will be solved if you move your `images` folder inside `public` folder which makes something like `public/images/forestBg.jpg` and use it as `./images/forestBg.jpg` or `/images/forestBg.jpg`.

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

While using the image paths if it not loading properly, use **require** in front as the correct image path would not be recognized properly without using that. So you can try this code:

```
const [selectedBgImg,setSelectedBgImg] = useState(require('../images/forestBg.jpg'));
return(
<div className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center z-50  bg-cover`} style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${selectedBgImg})`}}>
    <select value={selectedBgImg} className='cursor-pointer' name="selectedBg"  onChange={(e)=>{setSelectedBgImg(e.target.value)}}>
                <option value={require("../images/forestBg.jpg")}>Forest</option>
                <option value={require("../images/seaBg.jpg")}>Sea</option>
                <option value={require("../images/libraryBg.jpg")}>Library</option>
              </select>
</div>)
```

Make sure you need to use require while setting the default value of the usestate. Otherwise while loading the first time, the background image may not appear.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following code; it's working perfectly fine. I believe there might be an error in your image path, so please try correcting it.

```html
import React, { useReducer, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [selectedBgImg, setSelectedBgImg] = useState(
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1173777/pexels-photo-1173777.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
  );
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center z-50  bg-cover`}
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${selectedBgImg})` }}
      >
        <select
          value={selectedBgImg}
          className="cursor-pointer"
          name="selectedBg"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setSelectedBgImg(e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          <option value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1173777/pexels-photo-1173777.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1">
            Forest
          </option>
          <option value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/994605/pexels-photo-994605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1">
            Sea
          </option>
          <option value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1046125/pexels-photo-1046125.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1">
            Library
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```